# Error on executing rails server with postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I was trying to start with a simple application and I am stuck with the following error 
[image: This is the error I get in the termainal]

I tried to install gem install pg --pre , and other pg gems but the problem still exists.
Am I missing out something ?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

Had my *pg_ext.so* file under: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/

Copied it to: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/